# JRuby SAML Authentication

Tags: jruby, saml

I'm trying to set up a JRuby application to use SAML 2.0 Authentication against a simpleSAMLphp IdP.  The intention is to eventually authenticate against Microsoft ADFS, but that solution is still being built.

I've tried a couple of different SAML solutions so far (ruby-saml, samlr), and they all seem to fail under JRuby (but work fine under MRI).  I'm specifically using JRuby to utilise the JMS API and JDBC Connectors, so I can't really go back to MRI.

Does anyone know of a SAML implementation that works properly under JRuby?  I'm quite happy to go down the path of using native Java classes if that's required, but it'd really help to have a starting point that I can build upon.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is this application customer facing? If so, check out PingOne Application Provider Services. It's a hosted SAML SP from Ping Identity. You connect via a REST APS from your application and the service handles aol the complex SAML. Very simple to setup. The first connection is free as a bonus. [Note: I work for Ping]

HTH -Ian

Comment: Nope, this is an internal application.  We're looking to leverage SAML to replace an old Apache mod_pubcookie implementation, which obviously doesn't work very well when you start running things like Java application servers or using Ruby on Rails Apps :)